# Break a for loop when an error is produced Python

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

I want my Python loop (shown below) to work until an error is produced. I have seen elsewhere that you can use a while True inside a for loop but I am unsure if you can link this with an error. The error produced will be something along the line of this:

```
ValueError: No neighbors found for test samples [700], you can try using larger radius, give a label for outliers, or consider removing them from your dataset.
```

How would I incorporate that into my loop?

```
x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(100):
    raidus_class = RadiusNeighborsClassifier(radius=100-i).fit(X_train, y_train)

    new["radius"] = raidus_class.predict(X_test)

    if (sum(new.quality == new.radius) > x):
        x = sum(new.quality == new.radius)
        y = i
    print(i)

print("Sum of correct prediction: ", x)
print("At n-neighbours = ", y)
```

Many thanks, Ben.

Comment: You can use try..catch block and capture the error in catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done use exceptions in Python

Note the code below only stops when it encounters a ValueError

```
x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(100):
    try:
        raidus_class = RadiusNeighborsClassifier(radius=100-i).fit(X_train, y_train)

        new["radius"] = raidus_class.predict(X_test)

        if (sum(new.quality == new.radius) > x):
            x = sum(new.quality == new.radius)
            y = i
        print(i)
    except ValueError:
        break

print("Sum of correct prediction: ", x)
print("At n-neighbours = ", y)
```

We can catch any type of exception using

```
x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(100):
    try:
        raidus_class = RadiusNeighborsClassifier(radius=100-i).fit(X_train, y_train)

        new["radius"] = raidus_class.predict(X_test)

        if (sum(new.quality == new.radius) > x):
            x = sum(new.quality == new.radius)
            y = i
        print(i)
    except:
        break

print("Sum of correct prediction: ", x)
print("At n-neighbours = ", y)
```

Warning! Specially when using jupyter, using exceptions will ignore stopitteration or stop's, but this shouldn't be an issue as you have break included in your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `try` and `except` :

```
while True :
    try :
        # Your code inside loop
    except :
        break # If error occurred
```

You can implement this in `for` loops too :

```
for i in range(100) :
    try :
        # Your code inside loop
    except :
        break # If error occurred
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a try and except clause.

```
x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(100):
    try:
        raidus_class = RadiusNeighborsClassifier(radius=100-i).fit(X_train, y_train)

        new["radius"] = raidus_class.predict(X_test)

        if (sum(new.quality == new.radius) > x):
            x = sum(new.quality == new.radius)
            y = i
        print(i)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

print("Sum of correct prediction: ", x)
print("At n-neighbours = ", y)
```